# Cypher Query to get duplicate(same id) relationship between nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have  city nodes connected to each other  by  HAS_BUS relationships.
eg.

```
CREATE (:City{id:123,name:'Mumbai'})-[:HAS_BUS{id:22323,arr_time:234,dept_time:250}]->(:City{id:124,name:'Goa'}).
```

Though I wanted a bus id to be unique I mistakenly put bus with same id more than once i.e there are non unique HAS_BUS relationships.

Q1.How should I find out which ids are not unique
Q2.How should I find out which ids are not unique and delete them.

I wrote this query but got an **unknown error**

```
MATCH ()-[r:HAS_BUS]->() with count(r.id) as t match ()-[s:HAS_BUS]->() where s.id=t with count(s.id) as times,s.id as id where count(times)>1 return id,times
```

The database contains only 80 nodes and 6500 relationships.

I am actually missing GROUP BY feature of mySQL

[DATABASE Can be downloaded from here 6MB](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vbudhsnl34zesri/redbus.tar.gz)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that you want the bus id to be unique within your entire graph i.e. bus ID 22323  corresponds to exactly one HAS_BUS relation in the entire graph and is not repeated with different cities.

```
MATCH (c:City)-[r:HAS_BUS]->() 
WITH r.id as busId, count(*) as idCount
WHERE idCount>1
RETURN busId,idCount
```

note: not tested

will give you all busIds repeated more than once.
Then you can figure out which places you want to delete the duplicates from, or delete all and re-create the correct one.

The group by you're looking for is documented at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-aggregation.html

***Edit to remove all but one duplicate bus id: Make sure you have a backup of your database- this is NOT tested***

```
MATCH (c:City)-[r:HAS_BUS]->() 
WITH r.id as busId, count(*) as idCount
WHERE idCount>1 //Find all duplicate ids
MATCH (c:City)-[r2:HAS_BUS]->()
WHERE r2.id=busId
with COLLECT(r2) as ids,busId //find all relations for those duplicates
with head(ids) as firstId,ids,busId 
with filter(x in ids where x<>firstId) as idsToDelete //keep the first id and collect the rest
foreach (d in idsToDelete | DELETE d); //delete the rest
```

Comment: This isnt the correct way I guess. count(*) will calculate counts of total relation I guess.Executing this query gives only 1 row with busId as null and idCount as 7180(i.e total number of HAS_BUS relations)

Comment: Thanks its working.Actually in my database its rtid rather than id.I  still couldnot understand how this query is working.Whats happening at line number 2.WITH r.id as busId, count(*) as idCount. And whats wrong with my cypher query.

Comment: K good. Line 2 groups by bus ID. See the aggregation link I posted above. Not sure about your query, didn't really understand what you were trying to achieve

Comment: ok.As the non unique relations are completely identical i.e two completely identical relation with similar properties and ids.How should I remove one of them and keep the other.

Answer (score 0):

The code to remove all duplicates but one may be a bit simplified using tail instead of head-filter:

```
MATCH (c:City)-[r:HAS_BUS]->() 
WITH r.id as busId, count(*) as idCount
WHERE idCount>1 //Find all duplicate ids
MATCH (c:City)-[r2:HAS_BUS]->()
WHERE r2.id=busId
WITH tail(collect(r2)) as to_delete
FOREACH (d IN to_delete | DELETE d)
```